# mongoose, node, cannot use the method defined in user.model.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using node and mongoose to build an app. And when testing, there exists a strange problem. Here is my auth.index.js(for user login).

auth.index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var config = require('../config/environment');
var User = require('../api/user/user.model');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var auth = require('./auth.service');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next){
User.find({email: req.body.email}, function (err, user){
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    } else if (!user) {
        return res.json({message: 'Invalid email.'});
    } else {
            if(!user.authenticate(req.body.password)){
               return res.json({message: 'Invalid password.'});
            };
            var token = auth.signToken(user._id, user.username, user.role);
            return res.json({token: token});
    };
  });
});
```

Here is the user.model.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: {type: String, lowercase: true},
  role: {type: String, default: 'user'},
  provider: String,
  date: String
});
UserSchema.methods = {
//check password
  authenticate: function(plainText) {
    return plainText === this.password;
  }
};
```

However, in the command window, it returns that

> user.authenticat is not a function.

I wanna know why, and does it mean that I cannot use the method directly or I need to invoke the method through **passport** ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misplaced your methods. It should be like this.

```
UserSchema.methods.authenticate: function(plainText) {
       return plainText === this.password;
}
```

See the following link for the complete example. https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications

Comment: I tried, but still return user.authenticate is not a function.

Comment: are you exporting like this? module.exports = User;

Comment: like this: module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'User');

Comment: You should do it in same way which was there in above answer link.